# Row locks on select

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a stored procedure which does the following:

1. selects top N from table
2. sets these rows as processed
3. returns these rows to the client

Here is roughly how I am doing it in Sybase ASE:

```
set rowcount @count

begin tran get_items
  insert into #temp_table
  select item
  from available_item
  where is_processed = 0

  update available_item
  set is_processed = 1
  from available_item, #temp_table
  where available_item.item = #temp_table.item

  # select the processed items...

commit trans
```

I am wondering whether there is a race condition here. If two separate processes execute this stored procedure at the same time, could they select and mark processed the same data? Or does having it in a transaction stop this?

If not, is there a way to hold locks on selected rows?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the details will depend on your tables locking scheme.  Allpages, pages and row level locking will have different impacts on your ability to run concurrent updates on a single table.  I am assuming a page/row level scheme to allow for concurrency.

Your query will grab an initial shared page/row lock, which will be upgraded to an update lock, which will then be followed by an exclusive row lock on the updated pages/rows.  No other processes will be able to make changes to the selected pages/rows for the duration of the transaction, but another process could read the selected rows prior to your update, which could lead to some inconsistency.

To get around this possibility, you can specify the isolation level in the transaction to either isolation level 2 (repeatable reads), or isolation level 3 (serialization).  You may want to read up on the specifics of each level to decide which you want to enforce, and the trade-offs associate with it.

In your transaction, you would use it like this:

```
set rowcount @count
set transaction isolation level 2

...
```

Something to note, is that depending on the number of records you grab in your query, you could trigger a lock upgrade which could prevent your concurrent transactions from executing, even if they are not looking at the same rows as your first transaction.  By default, the server will attempt to escalate to a table lock if it acquires locks on more than 200 pages/rows.  This can be changed either to an explicit value or a range of values and percentage, and is configurable at the server, database or table level.

Relevant Documentation:

[Transaction: Maintaining Data Consistency and Recovery](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X70716.htm)

[Performance and Tuning Series: Locking and Concurrency Control](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00938.1570/html/locking/CBDFFDAB.htm)

[Transact-SQL Users Guide 15.7 > Transactions: Maintaining Data Consistency and Recovery](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X70716.htm)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I have tried adding at isolation 2 below the select insert query but get the following error: `Error: SELECT INSERT cannot be specified with isolation level clause.` Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  You cannot use `at isolation` with a select into.  Use the session level setting instead: `set transaction isolation level 2` - I've updated the answer.